Could not resolve all files for configuration ':connectivity_plus:androidApis'. getting error while running project in android but iOS its working
Getting error while running in android
Multiple build operations failed.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':connectivity_plus:androidApis'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_inappwebview:androidApis'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_secure_storage:androidApis'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':fluttertoast:androidApis'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':connectivity_plus:androidApis'.
Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, returnDefaultValues=false}.
Execution failed for MockableJarTransform: /Users/nk/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33/android.jar.
Cannot create mockable android.jar /Users/nk/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-33/android.jar

I did gradle upgrade, accepted android license, flutter upgrade, flutter clean  still issue not resolved
Cloned flutter project app while am launching app its it's running in iOS platform in android am getting error like.

files for configuration ':connectivity_plus:androidApis'. Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_inappwebview:androidApis'. Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_secure_storage:androidApis'. Could not resolve all files for configuration ':fluttertoast:androidApis'. Could not resolve all files for configuration ':connectivity_plus:androidApis'. Failed to transform android.

flutter doctor:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.1, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1) ! Flutter recommends a minimum Xcode version of 15. Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2024.1.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.92.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources.

Above are flutter doctor result.
